# Touchpad misbehaves when laptop is resting on my stomach. How to prevent this?

Tags: home, laptop

I frequently use my laptop in this position of the person in the photo, laying on my couch or bed. The touchpad is very close to the edge of the laptop, so any "gestures" requiring multiple touches (scrolling, swiping, etc) often get screwed up because my stomach is "resting" on it and providing a point of touch. Then I have to either get up or push the laptop up onto my leg to use the gesture I wanted.

Normal mouse movement works fine though.

How can I still lazily use my laptop in comfort without my belly interrupting the touchpad?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a laptop tilt stand? If so, it probably doesn't have a non-slip ledge in front of the laptop area.

Comment: I suspect the easiest way will be to put something between your stomach and the edge of the laptop, so that your stomach rests on that instead of the touchpad. Not sure what would be best, though; it shouldn't be much taller than the laptop base (else it might get in the way), but large/flat enough that the laptop won't slide off it; and solid enough to distance the laptop a bit, but with a near edge soft or rounded enough to be comfortable…

Comment: @Nautilus I'm not using any tilt stand, so it sounds like I need one with a "non-slip ledge"

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you need to put some distance between the laptop and your body. Anything will do. Here are some ideas.

1. Roll a towel into a tube. Bend the towel tube with the ends towards you and the middle away from you. The ends of the towel tube will support the laptop on your body.
2. Use a fitness noodle instead of a towel tube.
3. Any other flat flexible object you have around.